# Named Formatting with an ExpandoObject

Tags: .net, string-formatting

What I have is an `ExpandoObject` with a dynamic number of properties.

I would like to use this object to format a string using a named format expression, similar to what is done [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/14/named-formats-redux.aspx)

Unfortunately none of Phil & friends' implementations will work with an `ExpandoObject`, so I was hoping someone had come across a solution that will work?

I'm open to using a dictionary in place of the `ExpandoObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can use an ExpandoObject... I added the [NETFx String.FormatWith Extension Method](http://nuget.org/packages/netfx-System.StringFormatWith/) nuget package (it's essentially Henri Wiechers solution from Phil's post)

Instead of using it as an extension method though (that will cause a compiler error) you have to use it as a static method like this:

`var str = StringFormatWithExtension.FormatWith(string, ExpandoObject);`

Comment: Daniel Cazzulino pointed out to me on twitter that my ExpandoObject was typed as dynamic and so I could not use the extension method. If the type is ExpandoObject you can use the extension method.